# Cannot connect from host to exposed port inside container

Tags: c#, docker, docker-network

I have a simple application which listen for http request on port 5001 and return "hello" when a http request comes on that port.
Then i build the image for the application and ran the container with port mapping `docker run -dp 5001:5001 --name web-server web-server` but when i go to the browser and hit localhost:5001 it just doesn't work.
So, i ssh into the container and `curl localhost:5001`, this one works.
Can you tell me what could be possibly wrong or misconfigured?

Here is my `Dockerfile` file

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./bin/Release/net5.0 .
EXPOSE 5001
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebServerFromScratch.dll"]
```

and the NetworkSettings in the `docker container inspect`

```
"Ports": {
             "5001/tcp": [
             {
               "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
               "HostPort": "5001"
             },
             {
               "HostIp": "::",
               "HostPort": "5001"
             }]
         },
"Networks": {
                "bridge": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "NetworkID": "f227d735df3f23edc2f2aaf1a800bdeb70cf60caf50e08dc6b594b94cb38a1fb",
                    "EndpointID": "824ee71d4ed0a7e08080aeb728cf1f6821c5cdd7e2afbd6f1ca0327e68e47d44",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
```

Comment: What do you mean by doesn’t work? localhost:5001 will hit the local machine port

Comment: @viveknuna it doesn't return "hello" as i expected

Comment: Is there any error?

Comment: Chrome doesn't show anything but "This page isn’t working. localhost didn’t send any data." But localhost:5001 on the host machine should map to the localhost:5001 in the container, isn't it?

Comment: Do you see any error in browser console?

Comment: No, it doesn't. If i ```curl http://localhost:5001``` from the host, i get "curl: the underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly". Guess i did something wrong with the port mapping

Comment: Yes, i actually did. That's what i did from the beginning, but i wanted to make sure that the browser has nothing to do with the problem i'm facing so i also ```curl``` the url

Comment: You need to mention the protocol also with port with expose

Comment: do you mean the EXPOSE in the Dockerfile?

Comment: On what IP/interface is listening the webserver inside the container? Localhost/127.0.0.1/::1 is not enough to accept connections from 172.17.0.0/16

Comment: @Steeeve the loopback interface is listening. So, do i need to change it to the eth0 to be able to forward network traffic to the host instead?

Comment: Try it out ;) I can't try it myself.

Answer (score 1):

In the `aspnet` docker image from Microsoft, there is a definition of the ASPNETCORE_URLS environment variable to a value of `http://+:80` which makes a dockerized app listen on port 80 by default.

If you look at the logs from the container, you should be able to see a message that it's listening on port 80 like this

```
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: http://[::]:80
```

So when you run it, you should map your external port to port 80 on the inside like this

```
docker run -dp 5001:80 --name web-server web-server
```

Then you should be able to reach it from the host using `curl http://localhost:5001/`.